# searching for a value in csv and returning the row multiple times

Tags: python, excel, csv

i'm a noob trying to learn python,

i am trying to write a script for a CSV file that has 30,000 rows of data.

i would like to look through every row for a number in a column and return the row every time it finds that number.

i have searched and tried many different suggestion and they don't seem to do what i need it to can anyone help me, if i'm not making sense please let me know.

here is what i have so far and it is only returning to headers:

```
    import csv

with open("test.csv", "r") as input, open ("result.txt","w") as result:
          testfilereader = csv.DictReader(input) 
          Age = 23
          fieldnames = testfilereader.fieldnames
          testfilewriter = csv.DictWriter(result, fieldnames, delimiter=',',)
          testfilewriter.writeheader()      
          for row in testfilereader:
                 for field in row:
                        if field == Age:
                             testfilewriter(row)


input.close
```

thanks all

Comment: Have you tried using Pandas?

Comment: hi no i haven't as im new to python not to sure how i would use them.

Comment: whats the name of the column

Comment: the columns are age name

Comment: Could you should some lines of the input csv file?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Pandas` as follows:

**csv file:**

```
Id,Name,Age
1,John,30
2,Alex,20
3,Albert,30
4,Richard,30
5,Mariah,30
```

**python:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("ex.csv", sep = ",")
print df[df["Age"] == 30] 

   Id     Name  Age
0   1     John   30
2   3   Albert   30
3   4  Richard   30
4   5   Mariah   30
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/index.html) module which is made for processing tabular data.

First: read your csv into a so called DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
```

Now you can filter the rows that you need by logical indexing:

```
result = df[df['Age']==23]
```

To get the result back onto disk just use the [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method:

```
result.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Comment: hi thank you all for the help but if i use pandas how would i get into a txt file or can i not do this

Comment: is a csv file fine as well?

Comment: yeah thats fine as well

Comment: If my answer answered your question, please accept it.

Comment: hi i have been trying to install pandas and i have installed anaconda and the pandas module is not showing do you know a better way for me to get the panda module on thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Since you used DictFileReader, you get a list of dictionaries. 
so you should search for the age in the field you want by using `dictionary['field']`.
like this:

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as input, open ("result.txt","w") as result:
     testfilereader = csv.DictReader(input) 
     Age = 23
     fieldnames = testfilereader.fieldnames()
     testfilewriter = csv.DictWriter(result, fieldnames, delimiter=',',)
     testfilewriter.writeheader()      
     for row in testfilereader:
         if row['Age'] == Age:
            testfilewriter.writerow(row)
```

Of course, if the field name is something else you need to change `row['Age']` to `row['Somethingelse']`.

If you just want ot iterate over the values you should use `testfilereader.values()`, but then there would be no point in getting the data mapped to a dictionary in the fist place.

You also shouldn't try to close the input there. It will be closed when it leaves the `with open...` block.

Comment: hi,can you tell me how i would search for multiple values in the age column

Answer (score 0):

hi all thank you for all your posts i have had some trouble with my computer and installing panda so i had to try another way and this has worked for me.

```
import csv
import sys


number = '5' 

csv_file = csv.reader(open('Alerts.csv', "rb"), delimiter=",")
filename  = open("Result.txt",'w')
sys.stdout =filename

#loop through csv list
for row in csv_file:
    if number == row[0]:
       print row
```